# Shadowbox overlay not transparent in IE 6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, shadowbox

When trying to use Shadowbox with IE6 the overlay transparency simply not works, it remains completely black. In all other IE versions (7, 8 and 9) the overlay works just fine. Do you guys have any idea to why this is happening?

If you wanna check out what I'm talking about, you can test the examples on the project's web site, they also do not work in IE 6. You might notice that the buttons are also not displayed, as they are .png images with transparent background, however this can be easily fixed by creating .gif images and setting them specifically for IE6.

Links:
Main page: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

Thanks,

Comment: works fine in my ie6... screenshot?

Comment: I was testing it with IE Tester... I guess it's probably a bug of the program. Thanks

Comment: Mine too...weird. In my case it doesn't display a transparent overlay, only a black background. I'll try to see if in a raw IE6 version I can get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously advice you to give up, because people that still use IE6 are seeing a weird, ugly, cracked web all the time and they just dont care. You may spend days struggling with weird ways of overcoming a problem that comes from the simple fact that ie6 was not made for transparency at all.

GIFs wont work for you. Wanna know why? Because opacity of gifs is either 100% or 0%. In Shadowbox you will want middle opacity, like 50% or 70%. PNGs might work with pngalpha js scripts, but they tend to fail in animations, which are used for shadowbox.

Please understand that i'm not flaming here, i'm just trying to be honest with you.